# Antisymmetrized Product of Strongly Orthogonal Geminal (APSG) method

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, reference-request

To get a deeper understanding of electronic structure methods, like Hartree-Fock, MP2, and Coupled Cluster method, there are many small programs (codes) available in Python, C++ or Fortran, for example, [Daniel Crawford's website](http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/wiki/doku.php?id=crawdad:programming), [Joshua website](https://joshuagoings.com/)

Does any one know any implementation of a simple Antisymmetrized Product of Strongly-orthogonal Geminals (APSG) method [(Geminal Model Chemistry)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1503773) for, say, two geminals (LiH, or H4, etc.) in Python or another programing language?

I will be grateful if someone can share this type of code (implementation) to get a better understanding of geminal based methods.

Comment: I am not sure of the difference between strongly orthogonal geminals (SOG) and APSG, but Q-Chem has an implementation of the former. If you have access to the former, then you could at least run some calculations, but I do not think you will be able to access the actual source code. See [this page of the manual](https://www.q-chem.com/qchem-website/manual/qchem43_manual/sect0042.html).

Comment: Possibly related, here is an implementation of the [Antisymmetric Product of 1 reference-orbital Geminals (AP1roG)](https://theochem.github.io/horton/2.1.1/intro_horton_overview.html).